# Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions

Tags: asp.net, rest, .net-core

Trying to change .Net core 1 to net Core2.1-> That time facing the below error.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions. Install/reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 2.2.0 directly to project  to resolve this issue. 
Project -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions (>= 2.2.0) 
 Project -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0). Project

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error recently.

What I have done to sort this out:

Installed .Net Core 2.2 SDK

Then in my project I have changed in all .csproj files:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

whereas before it was:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

This helped straight away and the error dissapeared.

Comment: I have changed to core 2.2 then im gettingSeverity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1107 Version conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.0 directly to project UL.IO.ECM to resolve this issue. 
 UL.IO.ECM -> UL.IO.ECM.Data -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 3.1.0) 
 UL.IO.ECM -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0).